# design a search function for high scale

Tags: search, solr, indexing, lucene, elasticsearch

(not sure if this is the right forum for this question)

I am very curious about how search in major site, say youtube/quora/stackexcahnge, works?
And I'm NOT looking for an answer like 'They Use Lucene Search engine'. I want to understand exactly how the indexing works there.

- Is there a different Index for text search than the autocomplete feature?
- Is it done in the background like map reduce.
- How exactly does map reduce help deliver results? (I know that it counts words in each document but what happens after that when I search for a keyword?)
- I also heard that google stopped using map reduce and now using cloud dataFlow [here](http://www.datacenterknowledge.com/archives/2014/06/25/google-dumps-mapreduce-favor-new-hyper-scale-analytics-system/) - how does that work?

Help Please :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I voted to close, because I think your question is too broad. Each bullet could form the basis of an SO question. That stated, I'll take a crack at answer how SolrCloud attempts to solve each of the problems you are asking about:

**Is there a different Index for text search than the autocomplete feature?**

The short answer is "yes". Solr has several options for [implementing an autocomplete feature](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester) and all of them rely on either building a separate index or being supplied a separate dictionary. You can also roll your own in an even more sophisticated fashion as the blog post ["Super flexible AutoComplete with Solr" demonstrates](http://www.cominvent.com/2012/01/25/super-flexible-autocomplete-with-solr/).

**Is it done in the background like map reduce?**

Generally speaking no. SolrCloud is based on the idea of [shards with leaders and replicas](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Shards+and+Indexing+Data+in+SolrCloud). A shard being a subset of your overall index. With a shard being comprised of a leader and possibly one or more replicas.

Queries are executed against all shard leaders. With assigning a particular shard to serve as the aggregator of each shard's response, but unlike map reduce where the individual node responses have all the data the reducing node needs, [the aggregating Solr shard may make multiple requests back to the other shards to figure out sort order](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/SolrCloud-Sorting-Problem-tp4023382p4023611.html) - for example.

**How exactly does map reduce help deliver results? (I know that it counts words in each document but what happens after that when I search for a keyword?)**

See my response to your previous question. In short the query is executed against each shard, aggregated by one of those shards, and returned to the requestor. What Solr does - Lucene really - that's the useful magic part that people most often associate with it is [Term Frequency Inverse Document Frequency](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/advanced-topics/scoring.html) indexing [usually with stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) on text searches. While this is not exactly what happens under the hood, and you can vary what's actually done via configuration, it provides a fairly good idea of what's being done.

Other searching, on dates and numbers, or simple textual values is done in a fashion similar to [database indexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index). That is a simplification, if you want to understand it more fully read the JavaDoc on [NumericRangeQuery](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/3.4.0/org/apache/lucene/search/NumericRangeQuery.java#NumericRangeQuery) for an in-depth explanation.

**I also heard that google stopped using map reduce and now using cloud dataFlow here - how does that work?**

If I knew the answer to that I would probably be working for Google and not answering StackOverflow questions :). Seriously whatever they've built is new PhD level work that as far as I know they haven't even release a research paper on, which is what they did with [map reduce that led to Yahoo building Hadoop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce).